# IE8 regex error Expected '/'

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to run the following regex in Javascript
`/[^]*?(:[rp][el]a[\w-]+)[^]*/`

In ie8 I get `Expected '/'`

The problem comes from the stylis npm lib and this is the line it fails on

`var pseudofmt = /[^]*?(:[rp][el]a[\w-]+)[^]*/ /* extrats :readonly or :placholder from selector */`

The error says it expects a / at `[^]` but I'm not sure why!?

Comment: Yes It is JS, I'll update the description

Comment: @chiliNUT It's valid. You need to choose `javascript` as regex flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Escape those `^`s; they are negating a character that does not exist: `^` → `\^`

```
/\^*?(:[rp][el]a[\w-]+)\^*/
```

(I'm removing the brackets because they are unnecessary).

¿Or maybe you don't want to check for the character `^` at all, and what you want is to match the beginning and ending of the string? Please elaborate.

**Explanation**: The caret (`^`), when outside a character group, indicates the beginning of the string. Within a character group, however, it indicates that the character group is negative: `[^a]` will match any character but 'a', while `[^]` is invalid.

Besides that, your regex is obscure, not very strict, and probably not what you want: it matches `'^^^^^^:peasant-with-slashes^^^^^^^^'`.